# Turn toward someone and speak an aside

Tags: verbos, solicitud-de-modismo

Say I'm in a small group of people chatting, and one turns to me and makes a brief, private remark?  Is there a nice way of describing that, i.e. of introducing the quote?

Answer (score 3):

The key word is `aparte`. It means “aside” (both the adverb and the noun) or “besides” (and a lot of other things not relevant right now). So, you can say `me comentó aparte que ...` or `en un aparte, me comentó que ...`, or some other variant.

> [**aparte**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=364en40)
>   [...]
>   **3.** m. Conversación privada que mantienen dos o más personas, al margen de otras que se hallan en el mismo lugar.
>   **9.** adv. Separadamente, con distinción.

<sup>Real Academia Española, *Diccionario de la lengua española*, 23.ª edición</sup>

Comment: That would be the translation for "aside." It seems to me that the OP asked about the situation as a whole, and that could be "Me hizo un aparte (y me dijo X cosa)."

Comment: @Gustavson I didn't mean to say the full answer was word `aparte`, but that `aparte` was the key to the answer. Proposed answers are inside the text. I edited to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

If you speak to the group, you can say:

> Se lo / la robo un segundo. (This will usually apply when the person you want to speak an aside to has an active role in the group, so that his/her absence will be surely missed.)

If you speak to your confidant(e), you can approach him/her and simply whisper in his/her ear:

> ¿Te puedo decir algo en privado? / ¿Podemos hablar un minuto en privado?

Comment: I want to describe that it happened, describe that Person A turned to B to speak an aside (and then kept chatting with the whole group).

Comment: @aparente001 So you want to describe the situation? The only phrase that comes to mind right now is "hacer un paréntesis," but the meaning of this will be much broader, as it may refer to any short activity the person undertakes in the middle of a longer activity. By the way, is there any way for saying that in English that you know of, I mean, interrupting somebody to talk to him/her in private, or being taken out of a group for a moment for that purpose?

Comment: How's this: Me dirigió la palabra parentéticamente.

Comment: @aparente001 Never heard that. The adjective/adverb "parentético/amente" is mostly restricted to linguistics and will sound really odd in any other context. I'd say something like: *Me hizo a un lado/Me sacó del grupo para decirme algo.* Can't think of anything shorter, sorry...